# How windows retrieve time at installtion..?

Tags: windows-services, windows-xp, installation-package

i just gave a- repair for my windows XP SP2 system.

on repair,-> window came up with setting- location, date and time ..

My question is...

Date time everything was accurate in it when window came up..

How windows is taking that Time exactly../ it was accurate..??

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, Windows queries the machine CMOS clock to get the datetime at installation/repair time.

Comment: Whats IIRC..??
instruction or....??

Comment: i need the way how they are retireving -The solution i mean..??

The solution to retrieve the same  manualy,,.!!

Comment: @pvaju896: IIRC = "If I Recall Correctly"  And how would you like to retrieve said time?  C#?, VB.NET, other?  If you're installing something on Windows, just access the system clock (DateTime.Now in C#).

Comment: Not DateTime.Now works from System time..
Other one counter- clock is running with BIOS..

It is actully retreiving value from BIOS(Other CHIp).. How can we retreive that couter value..??